# Orchard background task not persisting PartRecords to the database

Tags: orchardcms, background-task

I'm trying to use a background task to gather Likes/Comments from the Facebook Graph APi and use that to drive our blog's trending.

Here the `trendingModels` have already been populated and are being used to fill in the `TrendingParts.GraphId` and `TrendingParts.TrendingValue`.

I'm not getting any exceptions and the properties on `TrendingPart` point to the fields in the `TrendingPartRecord`.

Yet nothing persists to the database, any ideas why?

`_orchardsServices` is `IOrchardServices`

```
var articleParts = _orchardService.ContentManager.GetMany<TrendingPart>(
                                                            trendingModels.Select(r => r.OrchardId).ToList(), 
                                                            VersionOptions.Published,
                                                            QueryHints.Empty);

        // Cycle through the records and update them from the matching model
        foreach (var articlePart in articleParts) 
        {
            ArticleTrendingModel trendingModel = trendingModels.Where(r => r.OrchardId == articlePart.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if(trendingModel != null)
            {
                // Not persisting to the database, WHY?
                // What's missing?
                // If I'm understanding things properly nHibernate should push this to the db autoMagically.
                articlePart.GraphId = trendingModel.GraphId;
                articlePart.TrendingValue = trendingModel.TrendingValue;
            }
        }
```

Edit:
It's probably worth noting that I can update and publish the fields on the `TrendingPart` in the admin panel but the saved changes don't appear in the `MyModule_TrendingPartRecord` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change my Service to a transient dependency using `ITransientDependency`.

The service was holding a reference to the `PartRecords` array and because it was treated as a Singleton it never disposed and the push to the database was never made.